# Al usar un login sale este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, login

Buen dia

El dia de hoy que trate de ingresar al sistema que estoy realizando, no me habia pasado hasta hoy y llevo trabajando en el mas de dos semanas, me tope con este error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

[image: Error al pasar datos]

y este es el codigo js que estoy usando, (es para un login)

```
(function($){
$("#frm_login").submit(function(ev){
    $("#alert").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login/Validation',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(json);
            window.location.replace(json.url);
        },
        statusCode:{
            400: function (xhr) {
                $("#username > input").removeClass('is-invalid');
                $("#password > input").removeClass('is-invalid');
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (json.username.length != 0) {
                    $("#username > div").html(json.username);
                    $("#username > input").addClass('is-invalid');
                }
                if (json.password.length != 0) {
                    $("#password > div").html(json.password);
                    $("#password > input").addClass('is-invalid');
                    
                }
            },
            401: function (xhr) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //console.log(json);
                $("#alert").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+ json.msg +'</div>');
            }
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
}); })(jQuery)
```

/*         EDITADO          */
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del lado del servidor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y ya validaste cuál es el JSON que estás recibiendo? Pues, como para saber... posiblemente te está devolviendo un mensaje HTML con error o algo así

Comment: Ya intente mostrar algun mensaje por la consola y no me muestra nada

Comment: Te refieres a ese comentario `console.log(json)`? Está mal puesto porque lo pones después de intentar parsear data y **ahí es donde se está muriendo**. Tienes que revisar el contenido de `data`

Comment: Me muestra todo el html del login

Comment: Te lo escribo de nuevo: NO sirve revisar la variable `json` porque tu programa falla al hacer `JSON.parse(data)`. La variable `json` no se podrá revisar porque hay una excepción no controlada al hacer `JSON.parse(data)`. Si `data` no trae algo en formato json, tu `JSON.parse(data)` va a fallar porque recibe algo que no está en formato JSON.

Comment: En el console.log estoy pasando data, pero me muestra todo el html, es la imagen que esta despues de la leyenda /*EDITADO*/

Comment: La respuesta claramente no es un json, `$(this).serialize()` debe ser el problema, o bien el código del lado del servidor.

Comment: He añadido una captura del código del lado del servidor